# Does @id in JSON-LD need to be globally unique?

Tags: rdf, json-ld

### Question

Is it necessary for a provider of JSON-LD to make sure that the `@id` of a node is always globally unique or is it only necessary for `@id` to be unique inside a JSON-LD document?

### Example

Let's say we have two different articles at different web sites which are both licensed under [CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). They use https://schema.org/ with JSON-LD to describe their metadata. One article uses the URI [`http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/`](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) and the other [`https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en`](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en) as `@id` for the property [`license`](https://schema.org/license)

**JSON-LD of article A**

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Article",
  "name": "A"
  "url": "https://a.com/article",
  "license": {
    "@id": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/"
  }
}
```

**JSON-LD of article B**

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Article",
  "name": "B"
  "url": "https://b.com/article",
  "license": {
    "@id": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en"
  }
}
```

In the above example when I [check both license URIs with the schema.org validator](https://validator.schema.org/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fcreativecommons.org%2Flicenses%2Fby-sa%2F4.0%2F) I get

```json
{
  "@id": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.id"
}
```

Is the license property of both articles referring to the same or to different JSON-LD nodes? Is it the job of the consumer or the provider of the metadata to resolve the different URIs to the globally unique identifier https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.id?

(I can assume that it is a good practice for both the provider and the consumer to try to resolve different URIs to a globally unique one. However I am interested to know what the spec is saying about the above example.)

Comment: I’m somewhat confused by your use of "globally unique". The IRIs in both of your examples are globally unique. Do you maybe mean "canonical" instead?

Comment: Yep, I meant "canonical" in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the license property of both articles referring to the same or to different JSON-LD nodes?

They are referring to different nodes.

The fact that Schema.org’s Validator displays `https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.id` as top-level item on both of these pages can be confusing, but it has no relevance.  This is the Indonesian version of the license (it has the language code `id`, so it has nothing to do with "identifier"), which happens to be the first one listed in the HTML.

The extracted RDF correctly says that this Indonesian version is a translation (`frbr:translationOf`) of `http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/`.

> Is it the job of the consumer or the provider of the metadata to resolve the different URIs to the globally unique identifier […]?

It has to be the job of the data provider to specify exactly the right/intended IRI. After all, only they know what they want to convey.

These IRIs don’t have to be resolvable at all. It’s a good practice, but not required, and also not always possible (e.g., when using URI schemes like `urn`, `tel`, `tag`, etc.). And a consumer of the RDF is never required to try to resolve these IRIs.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the id is not necessarily a working URL but a way to identify a specific entity. It's just common practice to use the URL where the entity is defined, with maybe a hash value added if multiple entities are on that URL.

I'd say both articles should reference https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.id as that is the id the licence identifies itself as.